# Using angularjs to request elasticsearch as cross domain

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, cross-domain

I am making a web app using angularjs. I am making request on elasticsearch api. This is the code:

```
app.controller('usersDatas', function($scope, $http){
  $http.post("http://192.168.6.55:9200/userdata/_search", {headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
    data: "{ 'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': 'png' } } }"
    // Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
  }).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

This is error I have :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.6.55:9200/userdata/_search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have added this :

```
http.cors:
  enable: true
  allow-origin: /https?:/\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
```

to my elasticsearch (/etc/elasticsearch/elasticesarch.yml) config. I don't know if the problem comes from elasticsearch or from angularjs.
How can I solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are u using windows or linux based system or ios ??

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is browser issue First close all the chrome browser windows ...

- open terminal
- sudo -i
- (Your Password)

then type

- google-chrome --disable-web--security

Then try the link in that url

Answer (score 1):

You must add in HEADER Access-Control-Allow-Origin

PHP Example:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```